# Looking for ways to retrieve emails and display it in an HTML inbox page

Tags: python, html, web-applications

I'm trying to retrieve emails via a python script. I was looking to see if there's a way to retrieve them and display into an HTML inbox page. I know that I could just log onto my email and see my inbox, but I still want to see if I can retrieve my emails and render it in readable form.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to retrieve your Gmail inbox, Google's Gmail API is perfect for that use case.

First of all, here's the setup instructions for Python:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

Once you've got your Gmail project set up (including signing up and getting an API key), you can retrieve an inbox from the `Users.messages` data. The example Gmail uses in the first link (quickstart) retrieves Users.labels, so it should be a pretty basic modification to retrieve Users.messages using the same syntax.

Alternatively, Gmail has a REST API which you could use to easily retrieve JSON data using a simple HTTP request. See here:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/

Note: if you're going the HTTP request route, then you might as well use JQuery (Javascript library) to execute an HTTP request using the `$.get()` and/or `$.post()` methods.